# Redirecting with json object

Tags: jsp, servlets, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am having two combo box in my UI. The first combo box contains the list of country names and the second combo box contains list of states present in that country. From the first combo, when I select the country, then the name is sent to the servlet. Using the name, the DB is hit, list of state names are retrieved and converted into JSONObject. Now I am not able to pass this JSONObject back to the extjs file for populating the second combobox with list of states.

Here is the code for the js file:

```
    Ext.require('Ext.tab.*');
Ext.require('Ext.button.*');

Ext.define('Country',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
    ]
});

Ext.define('CountryCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.countrycombo',
    allowBlank: false,
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'name',
    store: {
        model: 'Country',
        data: [
            { id: 'China', name: 'China'},
            { id: 'Japan', name: 'Japan'},
            { id: 'Malaysia', name: 'Malaysia'}
        ]
    },
    listeners: {
        "select": function(obj){  
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: '/CellEditing/FormServlet',
                method: 'POST',
                params: {
                    data: obj.getValue()
                },
                success: function(obj){
                    alert('sucess');
                    var respText = eval('('+ obj.responseText +')');
                    alert(respText);
                },
                failure: function(obj){
                    alert('failure');
                }
            });                 
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('State',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
    ]
});

Ext.define('StateCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.statecombo',
    allowBlank: false,
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'name',
    store: {
        model: 'State',
        data:[]
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();
    Ext.widget('panel', {
        renderTo: 'pan1',
        title: 'Basic Panel',
        width:600,
        height:100,
        defaults: {
            bodyPadding: 10,
            border: false,
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: 'anchor'
        },
        layout: 'hbox',
        items: [{
                  fieldLabel: 'Country',
                  xtype: 'countrycombo',
                  width: 234,
                  margin: '5 5 5 5'
               },{
                  fieldLabel: 'State',
                  xtype: 'statecombo',
                  width: 234,
                  margin: '5 5 5 5'
               }]            
    });  
});
```

Here is the servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Inside Post");
    String selectedValue = req.getParameter("data");
    System.out.println(selectedValue);
    //This is the json string I want to send back to the UI
    //The format of this json is correct, I verifieded it printing in console.
    String jsonString = new StateHelper().getStates(selectedValue);
    //Below are the lines I am having the doubt, it is not correct.
    req.setAttribute("data", jsonString);
    req.getRequestDispatcher("combo.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

combo.jsp is the file containing both the combo box. Running this code, I am getting the alert with "failure" message.

Its telling: syntax error in this line:

```
var respText = eval('('+ obj1.responseText +')');
```

Please let me know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Try with: `var respText = Ext.JSON.decode( obj.responseText );`

Comment: got this: `uncaught exception: Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: `

Comment: My first thought is that your printed JSON is invalid, have you tried looking whats inside the obj.responseText ? Can you post that value?

Comment: when I try `alert(obj.responseText )` then I am not getting any message. At java side, the JSON looks like this: `{"data":[{"state":"Shanghai"},{"state":"Hangzou"},{"state":"Dali"}]}`

Comment: If that were the case, then your JSON  would not be treated as invalid, we need to see your actual JSON, you can get it from the response in Network panel (on Firebug if you're using FF or in the developer console if you're using Chrome).
I'm guessing that your server side JSON is not correctly quoted or something among that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var respText = Ext.JSON.decode( obj.responseText );

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts coming into my mind..

First why you are using POST instead of GET?

Second try to set request/response headers with following:

```
'Accept' : 'application/json'
'Content-type' : 'application/json'
```

Comment: Read this info in doc: `"GET" if no parameters are being sent, and "POST" if parameters are being sent' Since I am sending the cOuntry name as a parameter in the request, hence using POST

Comment: yes, of course you can send data using get as well.  `Ext.Ajax.request({  
                url: '/CellEditing/FormServlet?cOuntry=' + obj.getValue(),  
                method: 'GET',  
                ........ `